# Is it possible to have shared element transition animation across tasks?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions, shared-element-transition, android-picture-in-picture

I had a shared element transition animation between two fragments ex: fragment A and fragment B. everything worked perfectly.

until:
Had to make (activity B which holds fragment B) a singleTask and specified a task affinity which means that it will always open in a different task.

So the back stack will look like

| Task 1 | Task 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Activity A | Activity B |
|  |  |

Is there anyway to retain the animation and keep the two fragments in two different tasks?